# Making a firefox/chrome extension from 0

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

i have a website, its to exchange links, files... to say it quickly it's my 'version' of twitter+megaupload,

Well, users add links all the time and so on, but i would like user be able to syinch his bookmarks from the browser to the ones he has at his profile of mywebsite,

Where should i look into?
Basically i need to be able to:
- Acces bookmarks file (1)
- being able to send the urls to my service ( 2 )
- maybe adding the login feature (in the future)

I was google'ing about this for ages few weeks a go and i kind of give up, because i'm ok with PHP and JS, but with this plugin languages i'm very lost. So i decided posting here, wich always brings positive answers

(1) - > I don't even know where to start
(2) -> i was thinking to have a website.com/auto_import_no_confirm.php?url=[URL] and put it in a for each.

how many different languages and extension files do i have to work with? I really need any kind of tip with point (1)

feel like?
-edit-
Just found This -> https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/Bookmarks 
wich really looks like i need, but where do i place this code?
thanks!

Comment: This isn't the place to start either. StackOverflow is all about creating a curated set of specific answers to specific programming questions. You need a discussion forum where people can make subjective suggestions of tutorials or something similar.

Comment: Read https://addons.mozilla.org/en/developers/docs/getting-started and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Answer (score 3):

Might not be a bad question, but there are too many subtopics raised to answer that. (And there is too much tagspam as well. Break up your question into PHP- and Javascript-specific tasks, when you have devised the general application scheme.)

But to get started, download similar Firefox extensions (.xpi) and unzip them to inspect the general structure. You'll find examplary code for bookmark handling and invoking remote APIs pretty quickly. And basically you only need Javascript for the extension itself. (It sounds like your extension does not need much UI.)

And there are many tutorials on designing Firefox addons: http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/08/how-to-create-firefox-extensions/ or http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+develop+an+xpi

Comment: i didn't mean to spam with mi tags. i just want to let people know what i'm working with previous reading question, anyway, i edited. you are probably right. since i just got the edit community Wiki privilege :D i should behave... haha, ok, really thanks anyways!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: You could edit your own questions anyway. But you should concentrate on either Firefox or Chrome. Don't try both at the same time. Chrome extensions are significantly more difficult to develop.

Answer (score 1):

The good news first, you won't need much more than javascript if you just want to access bookmarks and send them to a server, neither on firefox nor on chrome.
But still you'll have to make yourself familiar with the apis of the browsers and learn how to develop extensions.
However, both Mozilla and Google provide all necessary information on their developer sites.
For Chrome, [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html) is a good place to start, you'll find the api for bookmark access [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html).
The Corresponding site for Firefox can be found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/?from=/de/developers/), with information on bookmark access [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/FUEL/Bookmark).